# Using JavaScript and having difficulty with a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing html comments inside  elements using `document.getElementById("X")`

what I'm trying to do is use the contents of the element for a conditional statement.

Instead of reading the contents of the div element it is writing `<!-- A -->` in the element.

is there something else I can use to read the comment to use for a conditional statement or am I missing something?

Here is a sample of the code:

```
if (document.getElementById("psy").innerHTML="<!-- A -->")
    {
    document.getElementById("ops").innerHTML='Do you approach or watch and just observe?</p>'+
    '<br /><a href="#" id="choice" onclick="go()">Approach</a> or <a href="#" id="choice" onclick="look()">Observe</a>.';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("ops").innerHTML='Do you watch and just observe or are you to freaked by seeing your dream lover in real life and leave?</p>'+
    '<br /><a href="#" id="choice" onclick="look()">Observe</a> or <a href="#" id="choice" onclick="run()">Go home.</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1) or [`===`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.4) to compare two strings. [`=`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) is an assignment.